# How to replace http:// with Tel:

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a plugin that forces my urls to start with http://. Therefore when I add a Telephone Link i.e. Tel:0800 the plugin loads this in the browser as http://tel:0800

I have tried both Javascript and CSS to remove the http:// in the link but not success

I need to be able to replace the automatically generated link of http:// with Tel:// after the html code has been generated.

Because this is a wordpress plugin, I can't just manually edit the page as the page itself is generated on the fly.

Comment: `this is a wordpress plugin`  Fixing the wordpress plugin would seem the logical route..

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest getting rid of the plugin.

But you can go through all links and replace their `href`. For instance:

```
document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='http://tel:']").forEach(link => {
   link.setAttribute("href", link.getAttribute("href").substring(7));
});
```

That searches for links whose `href` starts with `http://tel:` (via a [starts with](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-substrings) attribute selector), then loops through chopping off the first seven chars of them.

Be sure to put that code in a `script` tag at the end of the `body`, just before the closing `</body>` tag. If you don't control where the `script` tag goes, wrap it in a `DOMContentLoaded` event handler:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='http://tel:']").forEach(link => {
       link.setAttribute("href", link.getAttribute("href").substring(7));
    });
});
```

Comment: _Fastest gun in the west ... ;)_

Comment: @LGSon - Took typing in high school. ;-)